# Multiple CKEditor in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, ckeditor

I'm trying to put two `CKEditor` on the same page.
Here is what I did:
first the `ckeditor config.js`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.language = 'en';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

    CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('my_custom_style', [
        { name: 'Page Title', element: 'h2', attributes: {'class': 'general-title min'} }
    ]);

    //Config the KCFinder
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/laravel-filemanager?type=Images";
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token=";


    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
        { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
        { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
        { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
        { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
        { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
    ];

    config.removeButtons = 'Save,NewPage,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Flash,Language,About';
};
```

and then I have this two `forms` on the same page which has `textarea`

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('details', 'Details') !!}
       {!! Form::textarea('details', '', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Details...', 'rows'=>3)) !!}
          <script>
              CKEDITOR.replace('details');
          </script>
  </div>
</form>
```

and the second one

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('intro', 'Intro') !!}
      {!! Form::textarea('intro', '', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Details...', 'rows'=>3)) !!}
       <script>
          CKEDITOR.replace( 'intro');
       </script>
</div>
</form>
```

> The first one seems to be working well but the second one didn't appear to work.

Comment: I dynamically generate multiple CK editors with JS and after adding one another CK editor with button, the previous one is not editable or anything with that. It seems like a bug with CK editor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong here

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('my_custom_style', [
        { name: 'Page Title', element: 'h2', attributes: {'class': 'general-title min'} }
    ]);
```

this was my style, and it shouldn't be inside the main `CKEDITOR.editorConfig` it should be outside and it works OK

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.language = 'en';
    config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    ...........
    ...........
    ];

    config.removeButtons = 'Save,NewPage,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Flash,Language,About';
};
```

Now here outside of the main function comes the style function

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('my_custom_style', [
    { name: 'Page Title', element: 'h2', attributes: {'class': 'general-title min'} }
]);
```